# Do not allow a single "-" but still allow for negative values and money in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a bit of a time figuring this out. I was able to put together regex to allow negative numbers for money and decimals in a numeric field. However, the problem I'm having is that someone can put just a dash "-" and it does not bomb out. How do I allow for the dash, but it can't **only** be the dash?

Here is what I have. Tried adding something along the lines of `[^-]?` but it doesn't do what I need.

```
(-)?(\$)?([\d]{1,})?(\.([\d]{1,})?)?
```

Comment: use lookaround assertions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. basically "if there's a dash, it must be followed by digits".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression might work for your case:

```
^-?\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Starts with zero or one hyphens, followed by zero or one dollar signs then **one or more digits**, followed by zero or one groups of a dot and one or more digits.

Regardless of whether the hyphen, dollar sign, decimal part, or all are present, there needs to be one or more digits

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm guessing I was trying to over complicate it.